# Project Active Executable can no longer be iPhone 3.2

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I don't know how much you can help me because its under the NDA, but I recently updated to the OS 4 beta 3 xcode version. My project worked fine under 3.2 but under 4.0 parts are a not quite right I assume because it is still being developed.

Every other installation of the beta sdk I could go into the project settings and select the iPhone 3.2 sdk and then change the target iPhone OS in the top left of Xcode but not this one. If I select 3.2 it still loads on 4.0 it seems I only have the 4.0 simulator and the iPad 3.2 simulator.

Any ideas how to get the 3.2 Simulator back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that Apple has not included the older iPhone simulators in the latest beta version of the SDK. There is almost a 1GB dif between the two installations.

There may be a way to add all the old simulator and device SDKs by installing all the packages in the old version of the SDK (the newer one is missing the folder) but after trying to install just the ones I needed with no success I just reinstalled the old Xcode instead which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the 3.2 sdk from the iPhone
   Program Site.
2. Install it in a directory seperate
   from the 4.0 beta sdk.
3. Use the xCode in the 3.2 directory
   for access to the current sdk
   versions, and the Xcode in the 4.0
   directory to play around with 4.0

Remember if you want to submit an app to Apple you will have to build it with a non-beta toolchain.  I recommend never *updating* your sdk to a beta version, but instead keeping the beta in a seperate folder.

Comment: Although this is a way to get over it they provided the older sdks as part of the package in previous builds and so wasn't a problem and I had for sometime developed in both without an issue, but not in this one.